# Parameter passed to x-data but css class not applying

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I'm passing an integer (0 or 1) called `$highlight` to a component using Alpine; the default value is 0. Here's my component:

```
<div
    x-data="{ hover: false, highlight: @js($highlight) }"
    @mouseover="hover = true"
    @mouseout="hover = false"
    :class="{ 'bg-slate-700': hover || highlight == 1 }">
    highlight: {{ $highlight }}
</div>
```

Here's where I include the component:

```
<x-component
    highlight="{{ $this->isActiveItem($item) }}"
    wire:click="selectActiveItem({{ $item }})">
</x-component>
```

When I click on the component, I can see that the $highlight value is changing, e.g. I see "highlight: 1." My method, `isActiveItem()`, returns a 1. But the CSS class doesn't get applied, even though the value of `$highlight` is 1.

I am looping through a list of these components, so I need the class to be applied only for my "active" (clicked) item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this problem by adding an event listener to my component, like so:

```
<div
    x-data="{ hover: false, highlight: @js($highlight) }"
    @mouseover="hover = true"
    @mouseout="hover = false"
    x-init="document.addEventListener('highlightdropdownitem', event => {
        if (event.detail.key == @js($key)) {
            highlight = 1;
        } else {
            highlight = 0;
        }
    });"
    :class="{ 'bg-slate-700': hover || highlight == 1 }">
    highlight: {{ $highlight }}
</div>
```

This is how I called my component, adding the `$key` value:

```
<x-component
    highlight="{{ $this->isActiveItem($item) }}"
    key="item{{ $item->id }}"
    wire:click="selectActiveItem({{ $item }})">
</x-component>
```

Then, my `selectActiveItem()` method dispatches a browser event through Livewire:

```
public function selectActiveItem(Item $item, $key) : void
{
    $this->activeItem = $item;
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-itemdropdown');
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('highlightdropdownitem', [
        'key' => $key,
    ]);
}
```